Magento 2 create graphQL mutation - update prices
I need to create a Magento 2 module that will update the price from another store in real time.
I need to make a graphQL mutation: every time a user visits a product page or searches for a product in a search engine, the mutation fires and updates the price.
Response example:
{


products(filer: {sku: {eq: 234345}}){
    items{
        name
        sku
        price_range{
            minimum_price{
                regular_price{
                    value
                    currency
                }
                individual_price{
                    net
                    gross
                    currency
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}

Maybe someone has knowledge or access to a tutorial on how to do it. I can build a simple module, but I don't have much experience with graphQl. I will be grateful for any tips and suggestions
